# Restore Windows XP MBR without Windows XP disc

Tags: windows, windows-xp, mbr

Is there a clone of the windows recovery console for windows xp because I no longer have the disc to restore the MBR. I also need to be able to run this off a flash drive because my dvd reader is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I see you didn't install the recovery console locally then! or store the ISO.

There is the windows xp 6 file disk set
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310994

so-called "Windows XP Setup disks"

It can get you to a recovery console.

You could also try  a Windows 98 boot disk. Downloadable.. FDISK /MBR 
that might do it.

Maybe there are some more modern better ways and then that'd probably be a better answer.

Comment: I ended up finding just the recovery console to download and found a tutorial to make it bootable. ill make this as a answer because i basically did this.

Comment: well, better to either post what you foiund as an answer or in comments, but to post it, for others. Since you mention downloading the recovery console, I found this   http://forums.pcpitstop.com/index.php?/topic/150212-boot-to-recovery-console-wo-xp-cd/    mentions this link http://www.thecomputerparamedic.com/files/rc.iso   and credits wannabe1 from Geeks to Go.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with Linux. Either boot a USB stick; or if Linux is already installed, you can rewrite the MBR as a "final act", which will make it inaccessible (until you reinstall Linux).

First you have to identify the disk. In the Terminal:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

to list the partitions. The disk will probably be either `/dev/sda` or `/dev/hda`. Then:

```
sudo apt-get install lilo
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

`lilo` is no longer installed by default, so the first line will do it (on Debian-based distros, including Ubuntu) if necessary.

Comment: Thank you Ken, this solved the problem for me. I used a Linux Mint  CD to boot a Debian-based Linux.